# Unexpected token trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I keep getting Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'trigger' at line 1 column 0 with this simple trigger

```
    trigger CreateWorkRecordsX on Staff_Week_Plan_Creator__c (after insert) {        

        List <Staff_work_records__c>  WR1 = new List <Staff_work_records__c> ();

        for(Staff_Week_Plan_Creator__c o:trigger.new)
        {

            WR1.Report_Date__c=o.Start_Date_of_Week__c;

        }
                insert WR1;
}
```

Purpose of this trigger is to create new Staff_work_records__c record after Staff_Week_Plan_Creator__c has been inserted.

Very new to apex, any ideas?

Comment: I think you are creating a trigger directly Your Name | Setup | Create | Apex Classes (this is not the right way)
The correct way to do this is to go to the standard/custom object itself and click on the Triggers and clicking the new button there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error appears when you try to create an Apex Class with an Apex Trigger code. Those two metadata types are syntax-similar, but they are totally different. Check if you are trying to save this trigger as `.apxc` in your developer console.
If so, then that's your issue. You should save an `.apxt` instead.

Example:

[image]

The file on the left is a class, and the one in the right is a trigger.

Your code was wrong too, just like **itzmukeshy7** said. But I think that if this error appears after you made the suggested modifications, then I think my post will help you now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this ;)

Problem in this line

```
WR1.Report_Date__c=o.Start_Date_of_Week__c;
```

Here `WR1` is a `list` of `Staff_work_records__c` so you can directly update a property of it's element. Maybe something like this:

```
trigger CreateWorkRecordsX on Staff_Week_Plan_Creator__c (after insert) {        
    List <Staff_work_records__c>  WR1 = new List <Staff_work_records__c> ();

    for(Staff_Week_Plan_Creator__c o:trigger.new){
        WR1.add(new Staff_work_records__c(Report_Date__c = o.Start_Date_of_Week__c));
    }

    insert WR1;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Still the same exact error

Comment: @Kollo Can you please update question with the latest code?

Comment: @Kollo what is this field Report_Date__c ?

Comment: @Anzar Report_Date__c is a field of a new Staff_work_records__c record I'm trying to create

Comment: @Anzar, you were right about my code too. After I saved as trigger rather than class, your updated code worked. Thanks